# Specific button won't behave correctly

Tags: javascript

My code is supposed to do this: when a button isn't clicked in the correct order, when the user presses "Próxima dica", they come back to opacity: 1. However, the button "213" remains pressed, when he is supposed to get normal again until the user clicks "próxima dica" for the sixth time. What do I do?

```js
var clicks = 0;

function mudarOpacidade(event) {
  const a = event.target;
  a.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0.5');
}

function desabilitar(event) {
  clicks = clicks + 1;

  switch (clicks) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementById("dica0").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica1").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("dica2").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica3").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica4").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica5").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica6").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica7").style.opacity = 1;
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementById("dica0").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica1").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica2").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("dica3").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica4").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica5").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica6").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica7").style.opacity = 1;
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementById("dica0").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica1").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica2").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica3").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("dica4").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica5").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica6").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica7").style.opacity = 1;
      break;
    case 4:
      document.getElementById("dica0").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica1").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica2").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica3").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica4").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("dica5").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica6").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica7").style.opacity = 1;
      break;
    case 5:
      document.getElementById("dica0").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica1").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica2").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica3").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica4").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica5").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("dica6").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica7").style.opacity = 1;
      break;
    case 6:
      document.getElementById("dica0").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica1").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica2").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica3").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica4").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica5").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica6").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("dica7").style.opacity = 1;
      break;
    case 7:
      document.getElementById("dica0").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica1").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica2").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica3").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica4").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica5").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica6").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica7").disabled = true;
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById("dica0").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica1").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica2").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica3").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica4").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica5").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica6").style.opacity = 1;
      document.getElementById("dica7").style.opacity = 1;
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <button id="dica6" onclick="mudarOpacidade(event)">93</button>
  <button id="dica1" onclick="mudarOpacidade(event)">976</button>
  <button id="dica3" onclick="mudarOpacidade(event)">1142</button>
  <button id="dica6" onclick="mudarOpacidade(event)">213</button>
  <button id="dica2" onclick="mudarOpacidade(event)">615</button>
  <button id="dica7" onclick="mudarOpacidade(event)">987</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You really need to be using classes. All that repetition is absurd.

Comment: What is proxima dica?

Comment: @isherwood classes like java? I'm some kind of rookie in JS, but I'll look forward to learning how to code in it properly.

Comment: @Gosi "próxima dica" is a button that increments the var "click"

Comment: No. [HTML classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class), just like `row` on the container. They'd allow you to target and manipulate sets of like elements instead of one at a time, repeatedly. You'd set the opacity of _all_ buttons at once, then change just the different one. Two lines instead of eight.